# how i am able to select contact in campaign report

Tags: reporting, campaign, custom-report-type

Campaign is not directly related to contact but when i try to create a report type after selecting the campaign directly i am able to select contact object. can anyone please explain how i am able to select contact directly under campaign?.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know, i think you created the campaign member but not campaign.

Please refer this link under USAGE headings,

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_campaignmember.htm

Answer (score 0):

I think its feature provided by Salesforce to reduce the report creating effort of admins.

The relationship is like

Campaign  <--- Campaign member (junction member) ---> Contact / Lead

So ideally we should have option to select only Campaign member (junction member) but for better usability Salesforce have provided Contact / Lead as option which is more meaningful and useful .